# INFO keyspace equivalent in predis

Tags: php, redis, predis

I have recently started developing a project with `PHP` and `Redis`(`predis`). We can see all databases and their keys by running `INFO keyspace` command in redis-cli. I want to know how I can get database names and their keys count with `predis` and `PHP`. There is `dbsize()` function in `predis`, but it returns keys of a selected DB not all databases;

Answer (score 2):

I found it :)
`info()` function can be used for my purpose. It returns the databases and their keys in an associative array.